# "required: no arguments" error using "extends"

Tags: java

Right off the bat, I'm a beginner, so the issue may seem rudimentary.

Whenever I use "extends" and attempt to compile, I get an error message such like this one:

```
BoAMC.java:7: error: constructor Scout in class Scout cannot be applied to given types;
        olaf = new Scout("Olaf");
               ^
  required: no arguments
  found:    String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
./Scout.java:1: error: constructor PClass in class PClass cannot be applied to given types;
public class Scout extends PClass{
       ^
  required: String
  found:    no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
./Scout.java:4: error: name has private access in PClass
                System.out.print("\n\n "+name+" is out off the box.");
                                         ^
3 errors
```

The code in question:

```java
public class BoAMC{
    
    private Scout olaf;
    
    public void play(){
        
        olaf = new Scout("Olaf");
        
        olaf.test(2);
        
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
       BoAMC me = new BoAMC();
       me.play();
       System.out.print("\n\n --End-- \n\n");
    }
}
```

```
public class PClass{
    
    private String name;
    
    public PClass(String nn){
        
        name = nn;
        
    }
    
    public void test(int i){
        System.out.print("\n\n We do a little testing. "+name+" "+i+" out.");
    }
}
```

```
public class Scout extends PClass{
        
    public void scoot(){
        System.out.print("\n\n "+name+" is out off the box.");
    }
}
```

I do understand that there is an issue with the parameters (The String with the value "Olaf" in this case), yet I do not understand what specifically the issue is. Furthermore, I do not get the second error message.

As said before, I'm a beginner. I've found several posts with similar issues, but couldn't understand the solutions. Many people have written something about "super()". Neither do I know what this piece of code is supposed to do, nor do I know if it is relevant to my issue.

-

Solution:
Using "protected String name" and "super(nn)" solved the issue.
Thank you two!

Comment: `Scout` has no constructor which accepts an argument.

Comment: Inside `Scout.scout()`, `name` which is member of `PClass` is `private` and not accessible to `Scout`. If you want to access `name`, maybe you can make it `protected`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of a parent class is not inherited by subclasses.
add:

```
Scout{
    public Scout(String nn){
        super(nn);
    }
}
```